# How to declare a variable whose type is the generics of another object?

Tags: c++, templates, generics

Consider the following piece of C++ code:

```
int main(){
  MyObject<int> obj;
  foo(obj);
}
template <typename T>
void foo(T& objct){
...
}
```

In foo, the type of `objct` will be `MyObject<int>`.
I would like to create a variable in `foo()` whose type is the `objct`'s generics, in this case, `int`.
Is there a way to do that? Thank you.
**Edit**
Unfortunately (I think) I can't rewrite the signature because the function `foo()` is called with different type of objects, for example

```
int main(){
  MyObject<int> obj;
  MyDifferentObject<int> obj2;
  foo(obj);
  foo(obj2);
}
```

Comment: if `MyObject` follows good practice it has a `MyObject::value_type` or similar. What is `MyObject` ?

Comment: `template <typename T> void foo(MyObject<T>& objct);`?

Comment: @largest-prime-is-463035818 MyObject does not follow that practice ahah, it's just a class I created.

Comment: @jarod42 I'm sorry, what do you mean? The code above works fine.

Comment: I meant what is proposed in answers.

Comment: try to be more careful with terminology. The type of `obj` is not a template. A type is never a template, because templates arent types. The type of `obj` is an instantiation of a template. Small difference, but it matters. For example in max66 answer, `C` is a template, while `C<T>` is a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about defining `foo()` using a template-template parameter?

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename T>
void foo (C<T> & objct)
{
  /...
}
```

or also

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename T, typename ... Ts>
void foo (C<T, Ts...> & objct)
{
  /...
}
```

to be more flexible and accept also type with multiple template types parameters.

This way, if you call

```
MyObject<int>  obj;
MyDifferentObject  obj2;

foo(obj);
foo(obj2);
```

you have that `C` is `MyObject` in first case, `MyDifferentObject` in the second case and `T` is `int` in both cases.

This, obviously, works only if the argument of `foo()` are object of a template class with only template type parameters so, for example, doesn't works for `std::array`

```
std::vector<int>     v;
std::array<int, 5u>  a;

foo(v); // compile: only types parameters for std::vector
foo(a); // compilation error: a non-type template parameter for std::array
```

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to create a variable in foo() whose type is the objct's generics, in this case, int.
> Is there a way to do that?

If you can change the function signature, then you can do this:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(MyObject<T>& objct){
    T variable;
```

---

If that is not an option, for example if you want `foo` to allow other templates too (such as in your edited question), then you can define a type trait:

```
template<class T>
struct fancy_type_trait
{
};

template<class T>
struct fancy_type_trait<MyObject<T>>
{
    using type = T;
};

template<class T>
struct fancy_type_trait<MyDifferentObject<T>>
{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
void foo(T& objct){
   using V = typename fancy_type_trait<T>::type;
   V variable;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a trait that determines the first template parameter of any instantiation of a template with one template parameter:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct MyObject {};

template <typename T>
struct MyOtherObject {};

template <typename T>
struct first_template_parameter;

template <template<typename> typename T,typename X>
struct first_template_parameter< T<X> > {
    using type = X;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same< first_template_parameter<MyObject<int>>::type,
                                first_template_parameter<MyOtherObject<int>>::type>::value  );    

}
```

The trait `first_template_parameter` can take any instantiation of a template with a single parameter and tells you what that parameter is. `first_template_parameter< MyObject<int> >::type` is `int`. More generally `first_template_parameter< SomeTemplate<T> >::type` is `T` (given that `SomeTemplate` has one parameter).
This is a slight generalization of the trait used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67198608/4117728) and if needed it could be generalized to also work for instantiations of tempaltes with more than one parameter.
In your function you would use it like this:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T& objct){
    typename first_template_parameter<T>::type x;
}
```